# Error in opening perspective org apache hadoop eclipse perspective

Tags: hadoop

When I am adding MapReduced perspective eclipse as shown bellow screen I am getting error "problem opening perspective 'org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.perspective'".

I already copied hadoop eclipse plugin jar file (downloaded from net) in eclipse/plugins folder and HADOOP_ROOT/src/contrib folder.

also tired with extract and add 5 hadoop jar and pack it.

Could you please suggest how do i resolve this error and run MapReduced on eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new MapReduce project using a wizard.

If the wizard fails to start, it will give you more detailed information about the problem.